# JSON for Language Translation

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Fiddle: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EvProJ?editors=1010

I'm trying to use a json object to set values and text stored in a JSON object

I can do it fine this way....

```
var myJSON = { name:"Michael", age:25, city:"Chicago" };
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = myJSON.name;
```

However, I'm having difficulty setting values and text stored in a JSON object. Like so...

```
var language = {
  eng: {
    hi: "Hello",
    bye: "Goodbye"
  },
  es: {
    hi: "Hola",
    bye: "Adíos"
  },
  fr: {
    hi: "Bonjour",
    bye: "Au revoir"
  }
};

console.log(JSON.parse(language.eng).hi);
```

Can someone explain what am I doing wrong and how can I set this text/values dynamically using this JSON object?

```js
var language = {
  eng: {
    hi: "Hello",
    bye: "Goodbye"
  },
  es: {
    hi: "Hola",
    bye: "Adíos"
  },
  fr: {
    hi: "Bonjour",
    bye: "Au revoir"
  }
};

$('[data-language]').value = JSON.parse(language.eng).hi;
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" data-language>
<p data-language></p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to parse JSON as its already a JSON object.
Just do this `language.eng.hi`

Demo: https://codepen.io/dividapps/pen/OjMdoj

Answer (score 1):

JSON.parse is used to convert a Json string to an object.  However, `language` is already an object.

If you want to convert your object to a Json string use the stringify method `JSON.stringify(language)`.